# how do I pass the values after each iteration of the loop to a separate variable, or to an array for subsequent use/ use in the loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

```
public static void Run()
{
    public static string desktop = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

    //List<string> found = new List<string>();
    //MemoryStream memoryone = default;

    using (var result = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(result, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (string p in found) // List<string> found
            {
                            var pr = archive.CreateEntry("Found_" + p + ".txt");

                            using (var entryStream = pr.Open())
                            {
                                    memoryone.CopyTo(entryStream); // MemoryStream memoryone
                            }
                        }
                }
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"found.zip", result.ToArray());
    }

    foreach (string path in Paths.sWPaths)
    {
        List<string> my = new List<string> { "qw", "er", "ty", "ui", "op", "as", "df", "gh", };
                List<string> found = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(desktop + "//")
                    .Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(path).Name).Where(n => my.Contains(n)).ToList();
                
                List<file> Informone = Data.Get(desktop + path);
                MemoryStream memoryone = new MemoryStream(cUtils.WriteOne(Informone).ToArray());   
    }
}
```

how do I pass the VALUES after each ITERATION of the loop to a separate variable, or to an array for later use in the loop? (I warn you right away, I don't need to output the final value of the loop, but the values of each iteration)

I need to pass the values of "List < string > found" after each iteration to an array or to a variable

```
foreach (string path in Paths.sWPaths)
{
    List<string> my = new List<string> { "qw", "er", "ty", "ui", "op", "as", "df", "gh", };
        List<string> found = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(desktop + "//")               
            Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(path).Name).Where(n => my.Contains(n)).ToList();
}
```

for use in another cycle

```
foreach (string p in found) // List<string> found
{
       var pr = archive.CreateEntry("Found_" + p + ".txt");
}
```

I need to pass the values of "MemoryStream memoryone" after each iteration to an array or to a variable

```
foreach (string path in Paths.sWPaths)
{             
      List<file> Informone = Data.Get(desktop + path);
      MemoryStream memoryone = new MemoryStream(cUtils.WriteOne(Informone).ToArray());   //MemoryStream memoryone
}
```

for use here

```
using (var entryStream = pr.Open())
{
      memoryone.CopyTo(entryStream); // MemoryStream memoryone
}
```

Comment: What is `"List found"`? I see no reference to it in your code.

Comment: `List<string> found = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(desktop + "//")
                    .Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(path).Name).Where(n => my.Contains(n)).ToList();`

Comment: You already have it in a variable. If you want it to use it outside the foreach, add it to a list variable.

Comment: if I make a loop in a loop, it will lead to nothing, so I need to output this variable and use it in another loop

Comment: Which specific part of the problem does it not solve?

Comment: "I need to pass the values of "MemoryStream memoryone" after each iteration to an array or to a variable"

Comment: Could you put them in a list too? I mean that is not a good idea (having multiple `MemoryStream` open at a once) - but you can do it if you want to.

Comment: there are no other options?

Answer (score 0):

```
//create dict with objects s0, s1, s2 dynamically 
Dictionary<String, Object> dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
for(int i=0; i<sWPaths.Length-1; i++) {
string name = String.Format("s{0}", i);
dictionary[name] = i.ToString();
}

foreach (string p in found){
//change to your desired variable using string.format method
if(dictionary.Contains[p]) {
dictionary[p] = found.ToString();
 }
}
```